# Modify other .py file variable in runtime and save it

Tags: python

I have this file **snippets.py**:

````
snippet_list = [
"""
```lua
function FuncA()
    -- do A things
end
```
""",

"""
```lua
function FuncB()        
    -- do B things
end
```
"""
]
````

I want to load the variable snippet_list to my main.py, like this:

```
import snippets
for snippet in snippets:
    print(snippets.snippet_list)
```

Ok, but how can I modify this list `snippets.snippet_list.append('word3')` and saving all modifications to disk so when I open the file **snippets.py** I will see the new appended string?

Comment: Unfortunately python doesn't work like that. It only ever reads `.py` files to create objects in memory. You need some other form of persistence.

Comment: As for "other forms of persistence", the standard library includes several modules for storing persistent data in files. See for example [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), and [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible using Python as the code in snippets.py will not change.

You will need to save the code in some medium to achieve this. The most simple example of this would be a .txt file.

First you would need to put your text in snippet_list in a text file, and then rather than creating values of snippet list you would need to load them from a file.

```
with open("my_snippets.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
values = text.split(",")
snippet_list = []
for value in values:
    snippet_list.append(value)
```

This will result in all of the data being in an array in the same way that it was before.

Then to add new values to our text file we would do the following

```
word_to_add = "word3"
# open the file in append mode
with open("my_snippets.txt", "a") as f:
    # we need to write with a comma first so it can split properly
    f.write("," + word_to_add)
```

Now when you open snippets.py it will read the data from the my_snippets.txt file. The second piece of code will allow you to add another snippet to your text file, which will be read by snippets.py upon running.